# AVMIDIPlayer leaks memory

Tags: swift, ios8, avfoundation, midi

I would like to play a MIDI file on iOS 8.2 with AVMIDIPlayer.

This does work indeed, but for a very short number of times: the memory seems never to be freed, and it is eventually filled.

Below is my code in Swift 1.2, reduced to a bare minimum: everything takes place in the ViewController, there are no other classes, no delegates, no error checking, etc.

The interface has just three buttons: NEW (instantiates a new AVMIDIPlayer and prerolls), PLAY, STOP.

This memory problem happens on the Simulator and on an actual device, and the bigger the soundfont and the midifile, the worse it is.

I noticed that RAM grows when creating a new AVMIDIPlayer instance AND when playing the midifile (in the latter case you can get even +4Mb/sec).

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var mp:AVMIDIPlayer?

    @IBAction func newButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        mp = AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("ahVous", withExtension:"mid"),
                           soundBankURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("TimGM6mb", withExtension:"sf2"),
                                  error: nil)
        mp!.prepareToPlay()
    }
    @IBAction func playButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        mp!.play(nil)
    }
    @IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        mp!.stop()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```